# Spring-boot -error: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException, Required request part 'file' is not present

Tags: file-upload, spring-boot, multipart

I got this error when uploading file with Spring boot, I have tried the solutions online but none seems to help, any clue why this is happening:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2017-05-10T18:15:21.812+0000",
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException",
  "message": "Required request part 'file' is not present",
  "path": "/api/upload"
}
```

Comment: Do you have a name attribute on your file input tag?

Comment: I am using angular 2, I did this:  put.append('file', fileToUpload);

    return this.api.postFile ('/upload', input).subscribe(
            res => console.log(res.detailedResult),
            err => console.log(err)
        );

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this on my end and was searching for an answer.  I was able to resolve my issue by adding a ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter in my class that extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter:

```
public class AppConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

    ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter byteArrayHttpMessageConverter = new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter(); 
    byteArrayHttpMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(getSupportedMediaTypes());
    converters.add(byteArrayHttpMessageConverter);

    //add other converters here
}

private List<MediaType> getSupportedMediaTypes() {
    List<MediaType> list = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
    //Add whatever media types you want to support here.
    list.add(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    return list;
}
```

}